# How to use a bibtex (xml) library in word

Tags: bibtex, macos, microsoft-word, xml

I need to use ms word, but I want to use my bibtex library for citations. Therefore, I installed jabref and exported my library to an xml file. However, I do not know how to import my xml file into the citation manager. In which folder should I put it in. I am on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Isn't this a question just about Word? That makes it off-topic here, I suppose [su] is better.

Comment: I thought this is a very common question if you are forced to use word instead of latex for a project... However, I am happy to move the question if requested

Comment: Perhaps, but the question is not *about* LaTeX, and (La)TeX knowledge wont help you at all with answering it.

Comment: Agree, is there an easy way to move this question directly to Super User?

Comment: I think the only option is to flag the question for moderator attention and ask for moving to [su]. Edit: I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend `Mendeley`, which is a reference software just like `jabref`.

However it comes with a plugin for Word and allows easy insertions of citations directly.

It is similar to `Endnote`, but free.

Comment: I am also using Mendeley, but here I just wanted to use bibtex-->xml-->word citations

Comment: As I said, there's no need for that if you use a reference manager like Mendeley. However, the master bib source is saved in Sources.xml. I don't know where this files is located on Mac, but you probably can google that. If you put your .xml into that place with that name you will have all references available in all documents.

Comment: @C.Colden in fact, when you go to References -> Manage Sources you should be able to select a master DB regardless of where Word thinks the "default" DB sits.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have failed to find my sources.xml and also to select any source. I checked ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office, but nothing there. I also tried to change folder in the manage source, but nothing happens when I press the button. I will try to import bibtex into mendeley

Comment: Hey, it could be that if your master is empty the file Sources.xml does not exist yet!

Comment: Thank you Trefex, you pointed me in the right direction. I just imported bibtex in mendeley and then used mendeley plugin in word!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Happy writing

Answer (score 1):

Since neither Bibtex4Word nor [Docear](https://www.docear.org/) works for you, you may try Firefox with the [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/download/) extension and the Zotero plugin for Word.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working with OSX

Comment: Sorry for my total lack of knowledge about OSX.

Comment: Zotero certainly works with OSX. If you're experiencing issues with Zotero, you could post on Zotero forums.